# C3js: How to hide ticks on y-axis? Y-Axis label is cut off

Tags: javascript, c3.js

How can I hide the ticks on the y-axis?

I currently achieve it by editing `tick.format`, as can be seen in this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DanielApt/bq17Lp02/1/

I'm not happy with this solution, as the y-axis label is being cut off

[image: Screenshot showing the y-axis label is being cut off]

So how can I hide ticks without having y-axis label being cut off?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used a combination of [Chetan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2575755/chetan)'s answer and some further work:

I hid the ticks with:

```
.c3-axis-y .tick {
   display: none;
}
```

And I set the tick format:

```
axis.y.tick.format = function(){return 'fy'; }
//return characters with both ascenders and descenders
```

See this JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DanielApt/etuwo8mz/1/ for the solution in action.

Comment: You can also do it in the method: 
`  onrendered: function() {
       d3.selectAll(".c3-axis.c3-axis-y .tick")
           .style("fill", "none");
      } `

Answer (score 10):

1) Try setting axis.y.tick.count to 1, so that no ticks are shown except top, and bottom most.

2) Or try CSS to get ride of all intermediate ticks except top and bottom one like:-

```
.c3-axis-y .tick {
   display: none;
}
```

If axis label positioning is an issue try to position it somewhere else like:-

```
axis: {
    x: {
        label: {
            text: 'X Label',
            position: 'outer-center'
            // inner-right : default
            // inner-center
            // inner-left
            // outer-right
            // outer-center
            // outer-left
        }
    },
```

Here is the working code:- 
http://jsfiddle.net/chetanbh/24jkmvL5/

Reference Url : http://c3js.org/samples/axes_label_position.html

Answer (score 3):

In case someone still needs it, I put it in onrendered callback to avoid affecting all charts:

```
onrendered: function() {
      d3.select("#myChartContainer").selectAll(".c3-axis-x .tick line").style("display", "none");
}
```